# Добавить строки в таблице бд в зависимости массива

Tags: php, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть n-ое количество input.
Оно всегда разное, может быть 1, может быть 20.
Код выглядит так:

```html
<form action="/1.php" method="post">
<input type="text" value="1" name="more[1]">
<input type="text" value="2" name="more[2]">
<input type="text" value="3" name="more[3]">
<input type="text" value="4" name="more[4]">
<input type="text" value="5" name="more[5]">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Как добавить в таблицу базы данных столько же строк сколько у нас input в форме?
То есть в таблице должно создаться 5 записей.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Простенький пример. Как вставлять данные в таблицу, я надеюсь, разберетесь.

```
<?php

$names = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;

if (count($names) > 0) {
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        // тут вставлять данные в таблицу
    }
}
```